# Java build system options

Tags: java, git, build

I'm currently building a desktop java application in a very clumsy manner. The application is deployed on Windows, Mac and Linux. Here's my build process now:

On Windows:

- Update local repository
- Fire up Eclipse
- Refresh the project
- Double click the .jardesc file to generate an executable jar file
- Commit the executable jar to source control
- Open up the .nsi script and click the build button (I have NSSI plugin installed) to produce the .exe installer
- Upload installer to ftp server to publish

On Mac:

- Update local repository
- Run shell script to generate .dmg file using .jar in source control
- Upload to ftp server to publish

On Linux:

- Update local repository
- Run shell script to generate .deb file using .jar in source control
- Upload to ftp server to publish

I'd also like to include some extra steps in my build in the future, such as:

- Setting build date
- Setting the HEAD git commit-id
- Performing some code obfuscation

Any suggestions on how I can streamline and speed up this process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are serious about having a good build system, then I'd recommend learning and using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), which provides:

- Comprehensive project build lifecycle management based on a declarative project definition (pom.xml)
- A huge range of plugins, which I expect will be able to handle all the specific build steps you require
- Very good integration with Eclipse
- Full dependency management (including automatic resolution and download of dependencies)

This is not for the faint hearted (Maven is a complex beast) but in the long run it is a great solution.

Comment: You should also look at [Apache Buildr](http://buildr.apache.org/). It uses Maven repositories and gives you all the benefits of Maven but won't have you tearing your hair out managing a mess of XML. You can script your build process using Ruby instead.

Answer (score 2):

First step would be to just get everything building without Eclipse.

You might also want to consider using something like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) to automate some of this.  You'll still require build scripts.

A solution could look like

1. Update repository.
2. Jenkins detects update and builds the jar.
3. Jenkins saves the jar to some location.

Then you can have separate builds for each OS, also running in Jenkins.  These could be triggered automatically on successful completion of the first build.  These would each:

1. Pick up the jar from the previous build.
2. Publish the OS specific binary to an FTP site.

[Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) is a good start, but you may also want to look at [Apache Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) or [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), as these will help a bit with managing your build outputs and dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at Ant: https://ant.apache.org/

> Apache Ant is a Java library and command-line tool whose mission is to drive processes described in build files as targets and extension points dependent upon each other. The main known usage of Ant is the build of Java applications.

Also, a long list of build systems: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_build_automation_software

Comment: Wikipedia lists don't give a quick overview. It might also be worth mentioning buildr: http://buildr.apache.org/index.html